# how make executable script visible to 'which' on osx?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, path

to use lilypond from the command line, you are supposed to make a script, chmod it, and put its location on the PATH (see right-hand column [here](http://www.lilypond.org/macos-x.html)).  you are supposed to use .profile for the PATH change, but that didn't work for me, so i used .bash_profile.

that worked (why didn't .profile work?  and should i prefer .bashrc?), but `which lilypond` doesn't see the script, and i assume the reason is the same reason i can't see it with [findExecutable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.0.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v%3afindExecutable) in haskell's System.Directory.

is this so, and how do i fix it?

Comment: After adding the changes to your `.bash_profile` did you source it or reopen your session?

Comment: You probably actually want to use `.bashrc` (see this page for details: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html ), but why don't you post the line where you add the executables directory to `PATH` so we can take a look.

Comment: `PATH="~/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH` 
hm, actually it turns out `~` in the PATH does not work for `which`, even though it allows executables to be found.  it works fine if i replace `~` with its written-out equivalent.  why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash doesn't expand `~` inside double quotes. Use `export PATH=~/bin:"$PATH"` instead.

If both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` exist, Bash only reads `~/.bash_profile` when invoked as an interactive login shell. Terminal and iTerm 2 open new shells as login shells, so Bash reads `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html.